# Create new instance of certain user type

Tags: lua, tolua++, meta-method

I'm using tolua++ to automatically expose C++ types to Lua. It seems that when I expose some type, e.g.

```c++
struct TestComponent
{
   float foo;
   string bar;
}
```

What tolua does (at least this is what it seems like to me) is add a new metatable to the lua environment (in this case it would just be called `TestComponent`) with some regular metamethods such as `__add`, `__lt`, as well as `__index`, `__newindex`, etc. It also has some custom functions (called `.set` and `.get`) which seem to be used when you get or set certain members of the struct/class. The type of TestComponent here seems to be just "table".

However, what it seems to lack, for simple structure definitions like above, are functions/methods to create a new instance of the type `TestComponent`, e.g.

```
a = TestComponent:new()
```

The question, then, is, how do I create a new instance of this type and assign it to a variable? For example, to hand it to a function that expects an argument of type `TestComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I used tolua++, but based on the docs it appears that if your struct had a constructor, then you could create the object with `a = TestComponent()` or `a = TestComponent:new()` (both should work, unless you have an older version of tolua++). Without a constructor in the C++ struct, the docs don't say, but based on what you state, it seems like the `TestComponent` becomes a regular table object with the given fields and associated values, in which case it does not make sense to have a constructor (the table is the object, you can't create multiple instances of it).

So if you can edit the C++ header of the struct to add a constructor to it, it'll probably work. If you can't do that, then you could define a constructor yourself (note: not tested):

```
function TestComponent:new()
    local obj = {}
    for k,v in pairs(self) do 
        obj[k] = v
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    return obj
end
```

You might have to filter the keys so you only get values (not functions, for example), or replace the loop with explicit assignments such as:

```
function TestComponent:new()
    local obj = {}
    obj.foo = self.foo
    obj.bar = self.bar
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    return obj
end
```